# how to run a program under different user's accounts

Tags: user-controls, window

my program (C:\Program Files\MyApp\Myprog) starts with windows startup; at device insertion Myprog.exe invokes another program (C:\Windows\comp.exe). this process works fine in the admin account in which I install the program but Myprog.exe is unable to invoke comp.exe when users account is changed. I want (C:\Windows\comp.exe) to be invoke in each type of account e.g admin group accounts and non-admin accounts. please help

Comment: To my mind this has to do with windows permissions and not with programming. If so, you're on the wrong site. I would suggest [Superuser](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add more information. Is it possible that the invoked program has to be run as administrator because of what it has to accomplish needs elevated permissions?

Comment: Okay - what does it mean , your program starts at windows startup? Is it started when an user logs on or when the system starts? In the latter case you may fail on trying to access registry of current user due to it is not loaded. Maybe the second executable is not started in the expected environment? You may want to install the called executable in the same folder then yours instead of the windows directory due to stronger limitation. Did you try to start it as a different user manuallly?

Comment: at system start.                                                                                                       Did you try to start it as a different user manuallly? : No

Comment: I would try different approaches to find out where it works and where it doesn't. Knowing if it runs under only when an user is logged on could be a sign that you use resources in your program that needs it. The only thing you would have to do is to start the program when somebody logs on. Actually there is a checkbox for forcing that in the user interface to define start tasks in windows (TaskScheduler)

Comment: to run "C:\Program Files\MyApp\Myprog.exe" at startup I wrote an script in my Inno setup installer to put this registry entry at installation time, "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run".

Comment: _Run keys cause programs to automatically run each time that a user logs on. The Windows XP registry includes the following four Run keys:_ taken from [https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/314866/en-us]. So the problem is not due to the user is not logged on, may be you have no permission to run it. Do you have any logging incorporated into your program to actually see what's going on? How do you access comp.exe from MyProg.exe? Can you explain why there is not just the MyProg.exe doing what is necessary? Why do you have to start comp.exe?

Comment: I came to my knowledge that it is a user access privilege issue, I have to put comp.exe in the same folder where MyProg.exe resides.